# curl reads list of image URLs from text file, saves images to local folder

Tags: curl, notepad++, text-editor

Using curl.exe on windows, this used to work:

I'd have a text file called imageURLs.txt containing something like this:

```
url = "http://image-website.com/43534?wid=800&fmt=jpg&qlt=80"
output = "43534.jpg"
url = "http://image-website.com/12345?wid=800&fmt=jpg&qlt=80"
output = "12345.jpg"
```

Then I'd run this command:

```
curl.exe -K imageURLs.txt
```

This used to download the two images to the same folder I ran it from. Now it seems to be outputting the image data to the command line. I'm not sure what would have caused this to change. Any ideas?

Thanks!

p.s.- i am able to download a single image just fine by running a command like this:

```
curl.exe "http://image-website.com/43534?wid=800&fmt=jpg&qlt=80" -o 43534.jpg
```

Edit: this seems to be a line-ending issue of some sort. Some text files work, others don't. Notepad++ doesn't seem to show me the difference in line endings. Any suggestions for other text editors or tools that can show me this info on Windows?

**Edit #2: Okay, I figured it out. I need LF at the end of each line, not CR. In Notepad++ do this: view - > show symbol - > show all characters. Find and replace \r with \n.**

Answer (score 0):

Curl wants the text file to have LF at the end of each line, not CR. In Notepad++ do this: view - > show symbol - > show all characters. Find and replace \r with \n.